# Serializing object to String in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, serialization

I have some objects in GWT which I want to store in client side as string, laster fetch them, decrypt it into the actual object, and do the needful with it. Can anyone suggest a way to do so? I couldn't find much documentation on this in Google, and the one or two similar question in SO didn't provide satisfactory answers..

Comment: Whats wrong with static map on client side ?

Comment: What I am storing is a complicated object. I can extract each field of the object as a string and store it like you said, but that would take  much time..

Answer (score 1):

[`AutoBean`](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) should be able to do what you want. It makes JSON out of your Java which can be sent through HTTP requests and turned back into Java objects on the other side. It's nice to use when you can use RPC.